# CAKEPHP application causing high cpu usage on my server, but fine on localhost

Tags: cakephp

I have built a cake application, I run it on a local machine when coding, and obviously deploy to my live website once done, but I am having issues, I am getting high proccesses/cpu usage on my live website, but getting no errors in my debug log/error log in cakephp, but in my server log, I am getting the following errors:

```
[Mon Dec 26 17:21:03 2016] [error] [client 52.39.17.74] SoftException in Application.cpp:641: Could not execute script "/home2/{removed}/public_html//{removed}/webroot/index.php", referer: http:///{removed}/css/front.css?1482790624
```

**Local machine cpu usage:**

[image]

**proccess information**

[image]

**And my proceess on my website:**

[image]

I have also checked the config files, and all seems fine, when it does load and don't get an internal error by hostgator, everything works normal. I have contacted their support who say it's my side rather than theirs. I am genuinely stumped and don'know how to fully debug the problem to fix, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### There are requests for files that don't exist

> `referer: http:///{removed}/css/front.css`

I don't know what any of the images in the question mean, but (assuming this is not deliberate) there is a reference to something in front.css that doesn't exist, and as such, these requests are reaching the CakePHP application code.

To identify what that is, simply look for/log the *request* url for these 404/5xx requests, and fix/remove the references to the missing files.

Given the error in the question, it's quite likely something like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'stuff';
    src: url('/fonts/uncommitted-file.eot'); # <-
    ...
}
```

I.e. a file which exists on a dev install, but is missing in production.

there will be one request hitting the php application for each file that is referenced that is missing. It is actually quite easy to DOS your own application if there are sufficient requests in parallel for files that don't exist, and is a common beginner problem.